# trouble using tinymce in django

Tags: django, tinymce

I am using django 1.6 and python 2.7. I am trying to integrate TinyMCE in django.I have included 'tinymce' in INSTALLED_APPS. Also, I included the tinymce in urls.py. While this works in admin, it doesn't work in templates.

my forms.py is

```
from django import forms

from .models import Question

from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 
             'rows':   30}))

class Media:
    js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js','',)
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ('title','content','tags',)
```

Also, I included the js files in layout.html as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/textareas.js' %}"></script>
```

the content of textareas.js is:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "simple"
    });
```

Lastly, my page which uses tinymce is (ask.html) extending layout.html :

```
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Any suggestion about where i am going wrong?

Comment: Check the HTML source. Do they load properly?

Comment: when i see the source, two javascript files are included due to {{ form.media }}. they are:                                                                                                                            
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js"></script> while the first one is in my static folder, the second one isn't there. what should i do?

Comment: Try including the second one in the the `Media` `js` tuple.